# Angular, access, write tuble

Tags: angular, typescript

Based on this post [Multidimensional array with custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516447/multidimensional-array-with-custom-class) ,I would like the:

- dropdown("Select an ingridient") => ERROR TypeError:
  "_co.selectedIngridient is undefined", first one, should be "none"
- dropdown("Select an unit") => ERROR TypeError: "_co.... is undefined" , first one, should be "none"

  and
- (click)="onCreateIngridientsNumberAndUnits(howToAssign)" => here I
  don't know, how to assign that new object, I created

working.

Data:

```
let result: [Ingridient, Number, Unit][]
```

Blueprint:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gxunx?file=src/app/app.module.ts
```

How to do it, what did I wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You currently in your StackBlitz doesn't even import/register/declare Material components/modules like `mat-select` and `mat-form-field`, so it simply will not work at all. Please first update your StackBlitz to include all necessary modules. Also you need to also add `angular2-uuid` as a dependency to the StackBlitz as well in the list of dependencies.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky can you try it again ?(on my place it looks good)

Comment: You may need to fork your StackBlitz to be able to save changes. Looking at the link you provided there are no listed dependencies to @angular/material in the list of dependencies and/or any imports of any @angular/material modules in `app.module.ts`. Your changes may simply not be saving/persisting.

Comment: Ok, i updated and forked it, is it better now ?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely much more ready for issue resolution. Thanks!