# Displaying, Updating, a List of custom tuples

Tags: angular, typescript

Based on this post [Multidimensional array with custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516447/multidimensional-array-with-custom-class) ,I would like to to display(`allRows`), update(using `onUpdateIngridientsNumberAndUnits(...)` und delete(`onDeleteIngridientsNumberAndUnits`) an entry:

```
        <div class="input-group mb-3">

          <!-- todo: How to assign? -->
          <!-- <div *ngFor="let row of allRows">-->

          <!-- [(ngModel)]="row.IngridientRow_name"  -->
          <input id="customId_Ingridient" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ingridient">
          <!-- [(ngModel)]="row.number"  -->
          <input id="customId_Amount" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="amount">
          <!-- [(ngModel)]="row.UnitRow_name"  -->
          <input id="customId_Unit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="unit">

          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button id="customId_Delete" class="btn btn-outline-info delete_ingridient"
              type="button">Delete</button>
          </div>

          <!--  </div> -->

        </div>
```

I got:

You can find it here:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gxunx?file=src/app/app.module.ts
```

How to do it, what did I wrong ?

Thank you in advance.